# tcpdump unknown device

Tags: tcpdump, solaris-10

I am trying to run tcpdum on Solaris 10 as root user.
I always get unknown device - even though I am using the name provided by

> ifconfig -a

How can I find out the right device name?

Comment: Can you post the results you are getting from the ifconfig -a command and the exact tcpdump command you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `snoop` in Solaris, instead of tcpdump. The interfaces that are plumbed can be listed with `ifconfig -a`. The unplumbed interfaces should be listed by `dmesg`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solaris box here, but no root access or tcpdump to test. However on my Linux box, i get the interface name from ifconfig which returns something like.

```
$ ifconfig -a

eth2    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr blah
        blah 
        blah

lo      Link enca:Local loopback
        blah 
        blah
```

Then feeding this into tcpdump gives:-

```
$ tcpdump -i eth2
verbose output suppressed
listening on eth2, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 96 bytes
```

What's your actual output from ifconfig -a?